# Register a Facebook access token in amazon cognito from a webpage

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, amazon-web-services

I am following the [SPA](https://pragprog.com/book/brapps/serverless-single-page-apps) tutorial by pragprog and the example uses google+ to store a token in amazon cognito. Login to google and registering in cognito works.

But registering an access token provided by Facebook app in cognito is not working as expected. I have registered a web app at FB and is using the supplied app id. Login to FB is OK and I get the access token.

html:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" ... onlogin="checkFacebookStatus()"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
        $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/nn_NO/sdk.js', function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : 'my app id',
                xfbml      : true,
                version    : 'v2.6'
            });
            $('#fb-login-button').removeAttr('disabled');
            checkFacebookStatus();
        });
    });
</script>
```

js:

```
function checkFacebookStatus() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            facebookSignIn(accessToken);
        }
    });
}

function facebookSignIn(accessToken) {
    AWS.config.update({
        region: 'eu-west-1',
        credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: learnjs.poolId,
            Logins: {
                'graph.facebook.com': accessToken
            }
        })
    })
}
```

I have registered the FB app id in Authentication providers in [Amazon Cognito](https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cognito/home?region=eu-west-1). Output to console shows my name, mail and the token. I run it with a selfsigned certificate on https://localhost so wireshark shows encrypted communication. The login to FB will fail if http and https is mixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must make a CognitoSyncManager() as outlined in [step three](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-js/). This will create an identity in the [amazon cognito](https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cognito/home?region=eu-west-1) identity pool which is accessed with the token provided by FB. In my case I have region eu-west-1 (Ireland).

```
AWS.config.credentials.get(function() {
    client = new AWS.CognitoSyncManager();
});
```